# Extend User Authentication in ServiceStack Mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, servicestack, authentication

I need graded authentication. (Only email is enough for authentication- no username,no password- This is so common for e-commerce site).

- Only mail authentication (Level 1 membership)
- Mail+Password authentication (via registration) (Level 2 membership)

What is your suggestion for this requirement?

- Get source code and change it (Update problem)
- Write your own AuthFeature (Long way)
- Will any option  available for it in framework?

Extra information

This is an e-commerce application. Users subscribe to newsletter. This is their membership. They are site's member. Their EmailValidationState is not set. But they are site's member.

Comment: If you use e-mail without verification, you probably want to send something to this e-mail. Using e-mail without verification can bring you accusations of spamming. Remember, that sending every content without e-mail owner consent is SPAM. And entering e-mail address is website form is not confirmation of owning that e-mail.

Comment: LukLed I added extra information to question.

Comment: So I can give you abuse@yahoo.com address and I am becoming site member. Is that how it works?

Comment: I will send an email to you. If you don't click any link on it I won't  send again. I will offer full registration to you time to time.

Comment: But what do you mean by authentication with e-mail?

Comment: I check cookie of client. If I found email information in it that is authentication with email for me.